# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable when using twice BeautifulSoup in the code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using a BeautifulSoup in my code to find all occurrence of 'tr' and 'td' but received an error for the second usage in the code.

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'cmm': 'onion', 'mkt': '', 'search': ''})
headers = {'Cookie': 'ASPSESSIONIDCCRBQBBS=KKLPJPKCHLACHBKKJONGLPHE; ASP.NET_SessionId=kvxhkhqmjnauyz55ult4hx55; ASPSESSIONIDAASBRBAS=IEJPJLHDEKFKAMOENFOAPNIM','Origin': 'http://agmarknet.nic.in', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6','Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0','Referer': 'http://agmarknet.nic.in/mark2_new.asp','Connection': 'keep-alive'}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("agmarknet.nic.in")
conn.request("POST", "/SearchCmmMkt.asp", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
result = soup.findAll("tr")
for y in result:
     row = BeautifulSoup(y,'lxml')
     k = row.findAll("td")
     for x in k:
        text = x.text
        print text
```

I received the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "commodity.py", line 15, in <module>
    row = BeautifulSoup(y,'lxml')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 175, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue and tells me correct way to use it.

Comment: Why are you cpassing `y` to `BeautifulSoup()` *again*? It is not a HTML string, it is a BeautifulSoup `Element` object.

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass `Element` objects to `BeautifulSoup()` in the first place. Just remove the `BeautifulSoup(y, 'lxml')` call altogether:

```
for row in result:
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    for cell in cells:
        text = cell.text
        print text
```